# PHP Displaying / Sourcing Base64 image data

Tags: php, image

I would like to generate an image from a base64 data in a PHP file to use it as an image manager to use on img tags :

```
<img src="myfile.php?image=<id>"
```

Actually my image data : `$data`, is a base64 string encoded with the Javascript method `FileReader().readAsDataURL()`

Here is an example of my data :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE ..... 9cSLKiyyEr+qf2jH//2Q==
```

And here is my PHP code :

```
$def = explode( ',', $data )[0];
$img = explode( ',', $data )[1];

$type = explode( ':', explode( ';', $def )[0] )[1];

header( 'Content-type: '.$type );
echo base64_decode( $img );
```

With the example above : `$type` is "image/jpeg" and `$img` the base64 data string without "data:image/jpeg;base64,".

But it's not showing any image :

[Broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRjLL.png)

Do you know how to fix my problem ?

Thank you in advance for your anwsers.

========== EDIT ==========

Thank you for your answers, unfortunatelly still not working from my side but displaying the outgoing data from base64_decode I saw this kind of specials characters :

```
Qa2q#BR�� 3b���CSr����$���
```

For this code :

```
// header( 'Content-type: '.$type );
echo base64_decode( $img );
```

So I tried with this header :

```
header( 'Content-type: '.$type.'; charset=utf-8' )
```

But my image is still not working.

@sercanarga if you have a few minutes, can you upload your code then I can try it live somewhere please ?

PS : after downloading my image by displaying it in an image tag ; and uploading it in a base64 decoder online, I got this issue : application/octet-stream mime type

========== WHOLE PROGRAM ==========

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG ... McYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcbYkvn/YlYYz8YKiHUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';

$def = explode( ',', $data )[0];
$img = explode( ',', $data )[1];

$type = explode( ':', explode( ';', $def )[0] )[1];
$type = explode( '+', $type )[0];

header( 'Content-type: '.$type.'; charset=ansi' );
echo base64_decode( $img );
```

Comment: download the image and open it in hex editor, then compare it to the original.. basic debugging

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code and ran it for myself. There is no problem. Probably the base64 code is incorrect or there is an error in the PHP file you sent the query parameter to.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7TP1.jpg)

Comment: No error is displayed on my php file and when I make an echo of the entire $data in a <img src="" /> on the src attribute, I can view my image

Comment: @LucasFAURE can you share all code? I did not understand your problem.

Comment: @sercanaga Actually here is my whole program (* check last edit)

If you want to test it, just convert an image to base64 and paste the string value in $data.